# How do I align card based button set in Google Apps Script to the end?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am building an add-on for Google Workspace using Apps Script and the card based GUI.

I am having trouble aligning a button set to the right/end using Apps Script syntax.

Using the [Card Builder Tool](https://gw-card-builder.web.app/#gahzZWN0aW9uc5GCp3dpZGdldHORgqpidXR0b25MaXN0gadidXR0b25zk4KkdGV4dKhCdXR0b24gMadvbkNsaWNrgaZhY3Rpb26CqGZ1bmN0aW9upFRPRE+qcGFyYW1ldGVyc5CCpHRleHSoQnV0dG9uIDKnb25DbGlja4GmYWN0aW9ugqhmdW5jdGlvbqRUT0RPqnBhcmFtZXRlcnOQgqR0ZXh0qEJ1dHRvbiAyp29uQ2xpY2uBpmFjdGlvboKoZnVuY3Rpb26kVE9ET6pwYXJhbWV0ZXJzkLNob3Jpem9udGFsQWxpZ25tZW50o0VORKZoZWFkZXKg) allows to align button sets to the start, center or end. The JSON output shows a key value pair of "horizontalAlignment": "END" for the widget.

```
{
  "sections": [
    {
      "widgets": [
        {
          "buttonList": {
            "buttons": [
              {
                "text": "Button 1",
                "onClick": {
                  "action": {
                    "function": "TODO",
                    "parameters": []
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "text": "Button 2",
                "onClick": {
                  "action": {
                    "function": "TODO",
                    "parameters": []
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "text": "Button 2",
                "onClick": {
                  "action": {
                    "function": "TODO",
                    "parameters": []
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "horizontalAlignment": "END"
        }
      ],
      "header": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

However, no apps script output is generated.

```
function buildCard() {
    let cardSection1ButtonList1Button1Action1 = CardService.newAction()
        .setFunctionName('TODO')
        .addParameters({});

    let cardSection1ButtonList1Button1 = CardService.newTextButton()
        .setText('Button 1')
        .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.TEXT)
        .setOnClickAction(cardSection1ButtonList1Button1Action1);

    let cardSection1ButtonList1Button2Action1 = CardService.newAction()
        .setFunctionName('TODO')
        .addParameters({});

    let cardSection1ButtonList1Button2 = CardService.newTextButton()
        .setText('Button 2')
        .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.TEXT)
        .setOnClickAction(cardSection1ButtonList1Button2Action1);

    let cardSection1ButtonList1Button3Action1 = CardService.newAction()
        .setFunctionName('TODO')
        .addParameters({});

    let cardSection1ButtonList1Button3 = CardService.newTextButton()
        .setText('Button 2')
        .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.TEXT)
        .setOnClickAction(cardSection1ButtonList1Button3Action1);

    let cardSection1ButtonList1 = CardService.newButtonSet()
        .addButton(cardSection1ButtonList1Button1)
        .addButton(cardSection1ButtonList1Button2)
        .addButton(cardSection1ButtonList1Button3);

    let cardSection1 = CardService.newCardSection()
        .addWidget(cardSection1ButtonList1);

    let card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
        .addSection(cardSection1)
        .build();
    return card;
}
```

I tried experimenting with the **CardService.HorizontalAlignment.END** ENUM but didn't find where to set it and couldn't find it in the documentation.

Anybody found a solution?

EDIT: I also filed a request to [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/236615814)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.